# How to make ZombieJS wait indefinitely for a site

Tags: node.js, headless-browser, zombie.js

I'm using zombieJS to scrape a veeeeeeeery slow site. I tried many things to make it go slower, but I'm receiving lots of

```
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'compareDocumentPosition' in null
```

errors.

I tried to add to my pressButton function the following:

> browser.wait({waitDuration: '700s', element: "pre"});

while initializing the browser with this configuration:

```
browser = new Browser();
browser.maxWait = 10000000;
browser.runScripts = false;
browser.loadCSS = false;
browser.waitFor = 500000;
```

but I'm still receiving the above mentioned error after a few seconds...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might apply to you: [Zombiejs jQuery nullTypeError 'compareDocumentPosition'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370771/zombiejs-jquery-nulltypeerror-comparedocumentposition/9438651#9438651)

your site is so slow, that the  tag cannot be found early enough from zombie. Would you please so kind, to open a new issue for assaf on github? We tried to track down the cause of this random-error earlier, but now I think it's caused because zombie should wait for the first dom element to be loaded

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar problem and it got solved by removing debug option, while creating instance of browser. Also downgrade to v1.4.1 as 2.0 is in alpha stage